# Real Time and Historical identification on App

Tags: website-design, gui-design, real-time-updates

I am making a dynamic dashboard. It shows real time and historical data.

Here is the screenshot of it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Lbz.jpg
[image]

All red arrows in the ss are symbolizes relative grids and charts. They all are connect to each other.

However, I am not comfortable with the 'Real Time' and 'Historical Time' design.

End users can't understand if the dashboard is setted to 'Real Time' or 'Historical Time'

If the dashboard is set to 'Real Time' option all datagrids and datachart should be feel like 'they are in real time mode'

Need your helps and thoughts.

Comment: Are the 4 blocks above your dropdown correlated with a time perspective switch at all? Are Blocking Sessions tied at all to a historical view? Your dropdown is very hard to parse at the moment.

Comment: @Mike Yes they all are relative. This page totally all 'Real Time ' or all 'Historical'. You are right but i have no idea to put another place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you could achieve the required result in 2 ways:

### 1. Widget Expansion

Every element on a Dashboard (especially real-time ones) is a **widget** and it shouldn't be allowed to change its natural behavior of being *live*.

Rather,

- It (each widget) should have a **Expand** button that brings it to the front/top/as an overlay.
- The user is allowed to interact with it to check historical data.
- Once done, they can close it and the Dashboard (which was running in the background anyway) is still real-time.

[image: Widget expand/collapse]

### 2. "Go live" button

Here, the user can interact with all the sections on the Dashboard itself. But the moment they do, a **Go Live** button appears on the top-right. If the user wishes to stay in the historical mode, they'll leave it as-is. If they want to get back to real-time, they'll click the **Go Live** button and it would refresh the section to flash **Now Live** and then it disappears.

[image: Button to make the widget go live(real-time)]

Comment: Thats the great answer. I will implement the things that you told me. Thank you. However, If The user wants to all of the widgets are in 'Real Time' or 'Historical' in Same screen. How can i make it if all Widgets are in real time or Historical ?

Comment: You can have a "Take all widgets live" button on top-right to get all the sections into real-time. But the only way of showing historical data is to interact with a section. Although, if want to give the user options like "Show data of yesterday/last week/etc", then I suggest having a dropdown or a timeline which the user can interact with.

Comment: I have drop down button in top of the datachart users can select historical or real time options as i stated in the image. However, in real time or historical mode All charts and grid doesn't feel like they are in the real time or historical. By the way, I started implement what you said. However, For all dashboard should be feel like in real time and historical mode.

Comment: How about having a green border on the Live sections? The "Go Live" button can be on the top-right corner of the screen, outside all the sections.
Any time the user clicks on any of the drop downs, the green border would disappear and the "Go Live" button would appear